# How to Create a Loop in SToredpeocedure and make a , string

Tags: mysql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a table with some data like id, Name , Forid

Now i want to get all Name in single variable with , spreted like this a,b,c

but it's forid is match

EX:-

```
Id   Name    forid
1     a       1
2     b       1
3     c       2
```

when forid is 1 then sp would return a,b

IF sql function is there it's ok but how to make this please guide me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use something like that. This is procedure in oracle but in SQL server i think you don't need more change

```
create or replace PROCEDURE p (x in number) AS
    z table_name.Column_name%TYPE;
    result varchar(100):='';
    cursor take is select Name from TABLE_NAME where for_id=x;
    begin
    open take;
    loop
      fetch take into z; 
      result:= result|| z;
      exit when take%notfound;
    end loop;
    close take;
    dbms_output.put_line(result);
  END p;
```